# Where can I find ECS and Fargate in the AWS Pricing Calculator?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an application that makes use of AWS ECS Scheduled Tasks with a Fargate launch type.

I'm trying to get a pricing quote for my whole architecture using the AWS Pricing Calculator, that I can send to the client I'm working for.

However, when I try to add ECS to my quote, I'm unable to find an option using the Pricing Calculator. If I query for "ECS" or "Elastic Container Service", I'm not left with any options. I've also tried querying for "Fargate" but only get a result for AWS CodeDeploy.

https://gyazo.com/32e9f68b2fa9e0dd395b5f0428469a06

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Not every service is supported** as explained in [AWS faq](https://aws.amazon.com/calculator/calculator-faq/):

> Q: I **can’t find the service** I’m looking for. Where are the rest of AWS services?

> A: We are actively working on adding more services. Let us know your top priority service in our feedback form.